# How to serve static files in adaptable backend hosting service

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I created a backend and in it I have used the express.static('public/assets') to serve static files to the frontend, but when I uploaded the backend to Adaptable, it is not serving the files.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: If you can provide more information about your setup, what guide/documentation you followed, how you got it uploaded and what it looks like, there will be a bigger chance to get help. Isn't adaptable.io made for deploying from github btw?